# About Java EE 6 Development Kit Bundles with JDK

Tags: jakarta-ee, java

What the JDK default install location for Java EE 6 Development Kit Bundles with JDK?
And do the Java EE 6 Development Kit Bundles with JDK consists of jdk documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Default Loction is C:\Program Files\Java

You can check this [location](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) about what it contains